# Callfile Set: RECORDINGFILE='whatever', failing

Tags: asterisk

I am using Asterisk 1.4.44-vici built by abuild @ build12 on a i686 running Linux on 2013-05-03 19:48:13 UTC

I have tried several ways to make the following work to no avail:
My callfile successfully calls out and records a message.
I want to send a variable that will be used for the recording file name.

In my callfile I have tried the following methods all failing:

- Set: RECORDINGFILE=whatever
- SetVar: RECORDINGFILE=whatever
- Variable: RECORDINGFILE=whatever

Then in my Extension I have the following, watch for wrapping:

```
[meetme-outbound]
exten => _9XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX1NXXNXXXXXX,1,MixMonitor(/var/spool/asterisk/monitorDONE/MP3/${SIPUSERAGENT}${EXTEN:1}${RECORDINGFILE}${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},$
exten => _9XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Dial(SIP/voipessential2/${EXTEN:21},,To)
exten => _9XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Hangup
```

THe above will record the file as if RECORDINGFILE, doesn't exist.  Very annoying!
What could I be doing wrong?  Is there a configuration setting that I am not aware of?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Greg Hill

Answer (score 0):

Variable will be set only on one direction of call

To get variable from other direction use

```
${SHARED(RECORDINGGILE,${BRIDGEPEER})}
```

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Detailed+Variable+List

Comment: I will give that a try and update you on the result.
Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I got the following error.  I am not sure how to register this function?
ERROR[25089]: pbx.c:1580 ast_func_read: Function SHARED not registered

Comment: I found on the most recent version of Asterisk, this error does not occur.